# Elasticsearch not getting enough file descriptors

Tags: elasticsearch, centos6, elastic-stack

Elasticsearch is failing because of the following bootstrap error.

`max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]`

I have set the value as root using `sysctl` and `ulimit` commands and verified using `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. Yet, the elasticsearch process does not get more than 4096 file descriptors. I even tried to start a new session from the root session I created but no luck there. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

For the .zip and .tar.gz packages, set `ulimit -n 65536` as root before starting Elasticsearch, or set `nofile` to `65536` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Please find the full reference [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html).

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have set the value using ulimit and also verified the value, yet elasticsearch does not pick it up.